# Greasemonkey replace string of JS code

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have a problem. There is a specific page, whick has a `<script>`, which I need to tweak some numbers in.

```
var series = [{"color": "#666666", "data": [[25.25, 0.0]], "label": "\u0418\u0442\u043e\u0433\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0435 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435"}, {"color": "#b72121", "data": [[1, 0.0], [2, 0.0], [3, 0.0], [4, 0.0], [5, 0.0], [6, 0.0], [7, 0.0], [8, 0.0], [9, 0.0], [10, 0.88], [11, 0.0], [12, 0.0], [13, 0.0], [14, 0.0], [15, 0.95], [16, 0.0], [17, 0.0], [18, 1.0], [19, 0.0], [20.25, 0.14894736842105263]], "label": "\u0418\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0443\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0436\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435"}, {"color": "#600101", "data": [[21.5, 0.0], [22.5, 0.0], [23.75, 0.0]], "label": "\u041f\u0440\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0436\u0443\u0442\u043e\u0447\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435"}, {"color": "#b72121", "data": [[26.75, 0.056600000000000004]], "label": "\u0418\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0443\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0436\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435-grade_breakdown"}];
```

the data

```
( "data": [[1, 0.0], [2, 0.0], [3, 0.0], [4, 0.0], [5, 0.0], [6, 0.0], [7, 0.0], [8, 0.0], [9, 0.0], [10, 0.88], [11, 0.0], [12, 0.0], [13, 0.0], [14, 0.0], [15, 0.95], [16, 0.0], [17, 0.0], [18, 1.0], [19, 0.0], [20.25, 0.14894736842105263]] )
```

needs to be changed to 1.0 everywhere. And I have no idea how to do this as I'm not an expert in JS nor Greasemonkey.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Answer (score 2):

Lets first take a look at the structure of your variable:

```
  var series = [
        {
              "color": "#666666",
              "data": [[25.25, 0.0]],
              "label": "\u0418\u0442\u043e\u0433\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0435 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435"
        },
        {
              "color": "#b72121",
              "data": [[1, 0.0], [2, 0.0], [3, 0.0], [4, 0.0], [5, 0.0], [6, 0.0], [7, 0.0], [8, 0.0], [9, 0.0], [10, 0.88], [11, 0.0], [12, 0.0], [13, 0.0], [14, 0.0], [15, 0.95], [16, 0.0], [17, 0.0], [18, 1.0], [19, 0.0], [20.25, 0.14894736842105263]],
              "label": "\u0418\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0443\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0436\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435"
        },
        {
              "color": "#600101",
              "data": [[21.5, 0.0], [22.5, 0.0], [23.75, 0.0]],
              "label": "\u041f\u0440\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0436\u0443\u0442\u043e\u0447\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435"
        },
        {
              "color": "#b72121",
              "data": [[26.75, 0.056600000000000004]],
              "label": "\u0418\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0443\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0436\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435-grade_breakdown"
        }
  ];
```

Okay, what do we have? `series` is an array containing multiple tuples, you can access them by `series[0]`, `series[1]` and so on.
A tuple is an object containing three key-value pairs. For example you can access `color` of the first tuple by `series[0].color`.
The values of `color` and `label` are `String`s. The value of data are again arrays.
For the second tuple you can access the `[2, 0.0]` array by using `series[1].data[1]`. Those values are again arrays. If you want to access the value `2` of the previous element it is `series[1].data[1][0]`.

Okay, for changing all data values you just need to iterate:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
        var tuple = series[i];
        var data = tuple.data;
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
              var dataContainer = data[j];
              for (var k = 0; k < dataContainer.length; k++) {
                    dataContainer[k] = 1.0;
              }
        }
  }
```

Of course there are some methods that do that job for you but in my opinion it is important that you understand how it works in principle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to replace all the `0.0` by `1.0`, apply that after your declaration:

```
series.forEach(function(element){
  element.data.forEach(function(data){
     data[1]= 1;
  });
});
```